# Displaying array elements using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to display elements of a JavaScript array. Code:

```
var name = ["one" , "two"];
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('MinamaisVards').innerHTML=name[1];
}
```

Can anyone tell me why does it display the letter "n" instead of the second element of array? I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: It looks like there is some other code that is being run that is changing `name` before the `window.onload` event is being fired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There already is a global with the name `name`, it's `window.name`, and it only accepts strings, so when you do

```
var name = ["one" , "two"];
```

in the global scope, and you get it back

```
console.log( name );
```

you get

```
"one, two"
```

and it's of type string, so `name[1]` is `"n"`, the second character in that string.
This is because what you're really setting and getting is `window.name`, and it does not accept an array, so it runs `toString()` on whatever you pass it.

Change the variable name to something that isn't already in use

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Not quite sure if I understand the explaination though.

Comment: @MarisP - In javascript there are windows, the main window is also the upper most scope, or a *global*, so when you're not in a function scope but in the global scope, any `var` attaches to the window, as in `window.variable`. A window can also have a `name`, which means that all windows have a built in `name` property, as in `window.name`, when you do `var name` in the global scope, you're in reality accessing `window.name` and that's a special property that **only** accepts strings, so anything you pass will be converted to a string.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in var `name` as its a reserved word, use `names` instead.

```
var name = ["one" , "two"];
 window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('MinamaisVards').innerHTML=name[1];
 }
```

should be

```
var names = ["one" , "two"];
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('MinamaisVards').innerHTML=names[1];
}
```